# datatool: How to read out values, if *.table-format is given

Tags: external-files, datatool

I have an external file, named `jobname.word.table` (*.table-format!), with its content

```
# aaa
# bbb
# x y type
3.1415927e+000 5.0000000e+000  i
2.0000000e+000 3.0000000e+000  i
```

(BTW: I can not change something in that style...)

I want to read out the value '5.0000000e+000'.

Can I do that with `datatool.sty`?

For `\DTLloaddb{test}{\jobname.aaa.table}` 
 I get '\DTLloaddb{test}{\jobname.aaa.table}...'

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.aaa.table}
# aaa
# bbb
# x y type
3.1415927e+000 5.0000000e+000  i
2.0000000e+000 3.0000000e+000  i
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\section{Does not work}
%\DTLloaddb{test}{\jobname.aaa.table}
\end{document}
```